# Extend models to handle different database schemas without changing the core model classes

Tags: c#, oop

I am developing an n-tier app for a client. The app uses a UI, a BLL, and a DAL.
I am programming against an interface to abstract out the database.  The BLL contains
my own models, i.e. Customer, Visit, order etc. The model also defines the interfaces including IRepository which describes an abstract dal object.

The app uses an instance of Sql Express and ships with its own local database on the client.  My client changes the database slightly for each customisation of the software release (dont ask) so I was wondering is there a way to handle these slight changes without changing my models.

e.g.  In customisation 1, a Customer model might look like this
ID, Name, Address, StartDate

In customisation 2, someone might alter the actual database to add a new column say "Email".  In customisation 2, they might want to show the email address on a report or in the UI.

I use my IRepository interface to create a new concrete db for each instance of the app. So in my BLL, I can inject a new IRepository of say CustomisationDataBase2. The interface has a GetSubjects signature so my CustomisationDataBase2 will implement this.  But from one customisation to the next, we have this difference in the 
schema where a new "email" field must be added to the Customer object in customisation 2 for eg.

Is there a way (maybe using extension methods on the concrete database) to make adding stuff to a model (in the case the Customer Model) easy without having to go and change my models each time ?  I realise I will have to change the UI to consume the different data and thats fine but ideally I'd like to leave my models as a seldom changing core set and use extensability (some how) to alter them.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not simple inheritance?  Create models with all of the core properties, such as `Customer`, then when a client needs additional fields create a new class, such as `ClientXyzCustomer`, that inherits from the Customer but adds the additional fields.  This allows you to only modify the client-specific models without making changes to the core models.  Let me know if that's even remotely close to what you're asking about...

Comment: Hi Troy, Yea I suppose I could live with that.  For any customisation that involves new fields, I could write models that inherit the existing core models. That keeps with the Open Closed principal (Bob Martin).  Many thanks for the reply.

The only issue with this is that it means I have to edit the BLL to add new classes, then I have to add a new Repository that can get these new models and then I have to edit the UI to consume them.  I was just wondering if there was a way to do it without having to edit all the layers  ?

Comment: I think in your core model you need to define the core properties and add additional Dictionary<string,object> for custom additional properties. Of course in your DAL and UI you need to access these additional properties to fill and display them properly. The only advantage is you don't need to change your core models every time a new field is added in the database, but obviously you loose the advantage of OOP in this case.

Comment: Actually Troy, your suggestion throws up a few covariance issues also. In my Interface, my GetSubjects is a List<Subject> but in a  concrete implementation, this cannot return a List<ExtendedSubject> for some reason even though ExtendedSubject is derived from Subject.   Has anyone any suggestions on how to make this as painless as possible ??